# prevent malformed id or invalid Id saved for lookup fields

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, lookup-field

When creating a new record of custom objectA, there's a lookup field orgAccountId binding to account.

Regular way is: enter orgAccountId such as 0000001 in the field, press enter, and it will search for matched org accounts.Then save the created ObjectA record.

Currently users can escape by entering random text as orgAccountId, and save. However, as random text is an invalid orgAccountId, it generates malformed_id, and throws error `EXTERNAL_OBJECT_EXCEPTION: We encountered an unexpected error. Try again later, or contact your administrator, who can verify the external data source settings and the external system's availability. Error received from the external system: \nCurrencyIsoCode, orgAccountId FROM Account WHERE Id IN (\'MALFORMED_ID\')\n ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:52\ninvalid ID field: MALFORMED_ID`

I am trying to create a validation rule to make sure all input accountId are valid lookup field values.

I tried `Not(ISBLANK( Account__c))`, but as Account__c field has value of `randomTextAbc`, it does not capture the case.

I tried `Not(ISBLANK( orgAccount__r.Id))`, but checking syntax failed, complaining `Error: orgAccount__x is an invalid object type for the OrgAccount__r field. Check spelling.`

How do I properly write the validation rule logics, so that to prevent creating records with illegal someAccountId as the lookup field value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is ObjectA an External Object? What is `RelatedObject`? How are External Objects involved here? (Please [edit]).

Comment: @DavidReed Hi David, thanks for the note. just updated, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: How are they entering in the random text? As far as I'm aware there is validation on lookup fields, as standard, that prevents random text being entered in?

Comment: @eaeaoo They entered random text. The field pops 'an invalid option has been entered' under the inputField. Users still clicked save and the record still gets saved. There's no built-in methods to prevent from saving. Do you know any methods please?